# How to disable the auto renewal of tokens oin react Okta Auth Js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, okta

I 'm using latest version of `@okta/okta-react`(6.7.0) and `@okta/okta-auth-js`(7.2.0) in my react application.
Renewal of token is automatically happens before 30 seconds of the actual expiry time. But I do not want this auto renewal, Instead I want to show the user a waring popup before the token expire, and if the user clicks on renew button in the popup, then I want to explicitly renew the token. If the user didn't click the button let the token expire.

How to disable the default auto renewal process in `@okta/okta-auth-js`. I tried the below code but it is not working.

```html
const oktaConfig = {
  issuer: "https://*****.okta.com/oauth2/******",
  clientId: "******",
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/implicit/callback",
  pkce: true,
  tokenManager: {
   autoRenew: false,
   storage: 'localStorage'
  }
};

const authClient = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig);

return (
 <Security oktaAuth={authClient} restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}>
  ...
 </Security>
);
```

Here I'm passing autoRenew property as false to tokenManager. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In case of @okta/okta-auth-js version 7.x
It will deprecated the configs on tokenManager.autoRenew but for the compatability reason it possible to configs there.
[image]

And it move the configuration to services.autoRenew
[image]
ref: https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js

So your configuration to disable renewable token is should look like this

```
const oktaConfig = {
      issuer: "https://*****.okta.com/oauth2/******",
      clientId: "******",
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/implicit/callback",
      pkce: true,
      tokenManager: {
       autoRenew: false,
       storage: 'localStorage'
      },
      services: {
       autoRenew: false,
      }
    };
```